# Running the same scripts on desktop and mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, jquery-mobile, mobile

If I have a set of scripts in one file that I need for both the desktop and mobile (jQuery Mobile) versions of a site, how would I serve them?

As I understand it, the desktop version would require $(document).ready as per normal, but jQuery Mobile requires the equivalent $(document).on('pageinit').

Is there a way I can write this so I only have to serve one file, or do I simply have to clone the file, change that one line and load each file conditionally?

Comment: You could abstract all the common functionality into one file, and then depending on the environment (mobile or desktop), use another 'bootstrapping' js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try something like this:

```
if (mobile) $(document).on('pageinit', initialize)
else        $(document).ready(initialize)

function initialize() {
    // stuff
}
```

(I'm assuming you already know how to detect mobile, as that's what's implied in the question.)